# how to fix a side-bar when the window is resized?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, w3.css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsT2K.jpg)I'm doing a school project, everything is done but the problem is when I resize the window to 800px which I set, the side-bar (I want it to be horizontally on the top) will occupy most of the page(vertically). whereas the side-bar in the desktop form is great, the size is what I want. definitely, it is because I use w3-mobile but I don't know any other way, Please help me out to fix it.

Comment: show us your code

Comment: you can fix it with css media queries

Comment: Try using bootstrap burger menu, it might help you fix your problem..

Comment: I am already using media query but its not solving my problem.

Comment: is there a way to change everything? like i write something else for a small screen..
like on the large screen it will show the card, and on the small screen it will just show the nav bar.. also i uploaded one photo check it please

Answer (score 0):

You can use media css. here is media break points

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px){ ... }

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px){ ... }

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px){ ... }

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px){ ... }
```

or

```
/* SMARTPHONES PORTRAIT */
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) {


}

/* SMARTPHONES LANDSCAPE */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {


}

/* TABLETS PORTRAIT */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {


}


/* TABLET LANDSCAPE / DESKTOP */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {


}
```

Comment: I am already using a media query but that's not enough
I dont know how to upload a file.. IT is in php

Comment: is there a way to change everything? like i write something else for a small screen..
like on the large screen it will show the card, and on the small screen it will just show the nav bar.. also i uploaded one photo check it please

Comment: I think problem is your media query css. please upload your code.
with help : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216464/how-to-insert-code-properly-on-stack-overflow